# No response from HR, Whats wrong?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

I interviewed @ relative large tech firm and got an cleared interview. I didnt know if they had more rounds, when HR called me with an intention to negotiate my compensation and so the conversation wasnt very pleasing for both end. After that didnt hear from her or the team for a full 2 weeks and then all of a sudden an email lands on my Mail extending an offer ( which seems to be below what she claimed she can do on that messed up conversation ).

Given 3 days to accept or deny the offer, so I quickly wrote back asking "Hey whats this? Slap in a face offer?, we gotto have a talk" in a polite way. No responses whatsoever.. So on the very last second of the deadline of the offer acceptance, I went and accepted it but since then still no responses to my follow ups and mail?? Whats the fuzz??

Okei:- Clearing up more details but wont change / edit my OP wordings. Firstly, I was over qualified for the role the had. Infact I applied for position A but during interview, one of the hiring manager, got to know that he needs me in his team than for the position I was been interviewed. This is to the point, I am pretty sure in background there were fight for my candidacy for more than one team. Not saying I am super talented but my skills matched more than one of their openings, so during 3rd round ( 5 people interview ), I could literally seen 2 hiring manager leaning my side without even asking many questions.

Now, after interviewed for many corp, My understanding is,generally top tier will have 5 tech rounds of interview ( I was myself an interviewer of this scale ), so  after 3rd round, when HR dropped a mail asking me to fill some details, I was assuming, that I have to fly to headquarter again and do some teach round and it is kinda asking for schedule call.

But as most of you HR knows, that when you have to come for compensation negotiation, you come with some hard headed tone and I went with my own set of expectation of the call. On the fly she asked me my expectation TC which I had no  clue of, and the mail she dropped was about some HR docs which I havent even opened. So she wanna muscle me when I clearly know my upper hand.

Anyways, here is my read what might happened, is this HR tried to block the offer at her best by being mean , but one of these 2 or both the hiring manager overthrew her agenda and she was forced to throw "Slap in the face" Offer.

During the first 2 weeks, I wrote 3 follow up mails asking for feedback, but she didnt get back... she hasnt even communicated that and during that messed up call, she said, this isnt a verbal offer so I wasnt sure if I cleared all rounds.

After the "slap in the face offer", I wrote politely about what she mentioned during call and what is in the offer is below what she has mentioned. I use the word " Slap in a face offer " in here only and thats is because, they were not bringing themselves on the table for negotiation.

It is rude

Comment: Could your "Slap in the fact" e-mail have been interpreted as rejecting their offer?

Comment: Nope, its HR playing dirty politics showing their true color. I could literally see the offer acceptance is being mailed to all party including cc that same HR and few others and hiring manager.

Now i am feeling sad, if I could reject this offer after accepting and signing it.

Comment: I think the clarification helps illustrate the situation... but not in the way you expect or hope.  I really think you need to take a deep breath, try some hard introspection, and work on improving a couple different facets of your professional life - because I have a feeling that most of the people reading this aren't casting you as the protagonist of the story.

Answer (score 9):

**Sorry, but I'm going to post a mean answer: they're likely slamming on the brakes due to your communication and attitude** - and my guess is that they were hoping you *wouldn't* accept the offer.

I mean, first up, try reading your question aloud exactly as you've written it.  It doesn't communicate clearly, it wasn't proofread at all, and it basically screams a lack of professionalism.  I mean, if I was involved in the hiring process and got communication from an applicant in the same style/effort, I'd definitely want to stop things and would wonder if maybe we should just keep looking.

Second... you've got a pretty bad attitude with the process.  I mean, you're describing an offer as a "slap in the face", saying they "messed up a conversation", and you're trying to badmouth the behavior of a company *you just agreed to work with.*  It's pretty unlikely that HR hasn't picked up on your outlook for the process.  That's why I think they gave you the low-ball: someone along the line decided you weren't that good of an applicant and was half-hoping you'd decline the offer.

My advice?

- Either decide that you're unhappy with the offered salary and start
  looking for a different job, or put the prior salary negotiation
  out-of-mind and don't let it fester into resentment - about the worst
  thing you can do is start this job and then let it sour.
- Put an emphasis on getting better at business communication.  Form
  full sentences.  Proofread.  Be concise.  Etc.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way for us to know what they are thinking.

In my opinion, you have shot yourself in the foot.  You had a back and forth over salary, which you said neither party was happy.  However, they still extended an offer to you.  To which, you essentially denied the offer by your response.  If I were the company, I would not hire you, as you are obviously not happy with the salary.

Comment: Depending on exactly how it was worded, the e-mail responding to the offer might even have been interpreted as rejecting the offer.